# Making a "Atari Breakout" type game on javascript. Was wondering about ideas on how to create them without having to do it manually

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I was wondering how I could go about with creating the bricks that are to disappear when hit by the ball instead of having to draw every brick manually. By manually, I mean creating each and every brick and using an if statement for each and every brick to check whether the ball has hit or not. I have finished everything else, here is my code so far: Thank you in Advance...

```
    <body>
    <canvas height="400" width="400" id="myCanvas"></canvas>       
    <script>
        "use strict"
        var a=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var c=a.getContext("2d");
        var platformX=170;
        var speed=0;
        var ballX=200
        var ballY=50;
        var ballSpeed=0;
        var ballBounce=0;
        var ballRadius=10;
        var interval=window.setInterval(createBall,17);
        var bullets=[];
        
        c.fillStyle="white";
        c.beginPath();
        c.rect(platformX,350,40,30);
        c.fill();
        c.closePath();
        
        c.fillStyle="green";
        c.beginPath();
        c.arc(200,ballY,10,0,2*Math.PI);
        c.fill();
        c.closePath();
        
        window.onkeydown=function(e){
            if(e.keyCode==37){
                speed=-6;
            }
            if(e.keyCode==39){
                speed=6;
            }
            if(e.keyCode==32){
                ballSpeed=2;
                
            }
        }
        
        window.onkeyup=function(e){
            if(e.keyCode==37){
                speed=0;
            }
            if(e.keyCode==39){
                speed=0;
            }
        }
        
        function movePlatform(){
            platformX+=speed; 
            c.clearRect(0,350,400,50);
            c.fillStyle="white";
            c.beginPath();
            c.rect(platformX,350,80,20);
            c.fill();
            c.closePath();
    }
        window.setInterval(movePlatform,17);
        
        function createBall(){
            ballY+=ballSpeed;
            ballX+=ballBounce;
            c.clearRect(0,0,400,350);
            c.fillStyle="green";
            c.beginPath();
            c.arc(ballX,ballY,ballRadius,0,2*Math.PI);
            c.fill();
            c.closePath();
            
            if(ballY>400-ballRadius){alert("Game Over");clearInterval(interval)}
            if(ballY>350-ballRadius&&ballX>platformX&&ballX<(platformX+40)){ballSpeed=-ballSpeed; ballBounce=-2;}
            if(ballY>350-ballRadius&&ballX>(platformX+40)&&ballX<(platformX+80)){ballSpeed=-ballSpeed; ballBounce=2;}
            if(ballY<ballRadius){ballSpeed=-ballSpeed;}
            if(ballX>400-ballRadius||ballX<ballRadius){ballBounce=-ballBounce}
        }
        window.setInterval(createBall,17);
        
    
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Look into storing the bricks in an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define an object constructor function that will create a brick object. You can then read the properties of the brick from this object in order to render it.

```
function Brick(x,y,width,height){ // as inputs you take the position and size
this.x = x; // adding attributes to the object based on the values that were entered
this.y = y;
this.width = width;
this.height = height;
}
```

When we want to create a brick object, we call the function as follows:

```
var brick = new Brick(x,y,width,height); //whatever values you want it to have
```

The second part of the solution is storing all the brick objects in an array:

```
var bricks = [];//initialise the array
var brickWidth = 30;//the default dimensions of the bricks. Change these to be whatever you want
var brickHeight = 10;
var xBrickPadding = 5;//the default spacing between bricks
var yBrickPadding = 5;
var minX = 0; // the dimensions of the area in which you want your bricks to be
var maxX = 100;
var minY = 0;
var maxY = 50;

//when you want to add your bricks to the array, probably at the start of the game or whenever you refresh, use a loop like this:
for(let x = minX; x<maxX; x+= brickWidth+xBrickPadding){ //loop over the x coordinates
   for(let y = minY; y<maxY; y+= brickHeight+yBrickPadding){//loop over the y coordinate
      bricks.push(new Brick(x,y,brickWidth,brickHeight)); //add our new brick to the array at each x and y position
   }
}
```

We now have an array full of bricks at appropriate positions, but we need to render them on the screen. Let's define a renderBricks function so that we don't have to render them every animation frame, only when we need to update them:

```
renderBricks = function(){
   for(brick of bricks){//loop over every brick stored in the array
      c.beginPath();
      c.rect(brick.x,brick.y,brick.width,brick.height);//read the relevant properties from the brick object in order to render it
      c.fill();
      c.closePath();
   }
}
```

The last part of code is the logic that will remove bricks when they are hit. Add this code inside your createBall function so that it gets checked every time the ball's position changes.

```
for(brick of bricks){//loop over every brick
   if(){//insert your condition here to check if the ball has collided or not. You can use the properties brick.x, brick.y, brick.width and brick.height
      bricks.splice(bricks.indexOf(brick),1); //if so, remove the brick from the array
      renderBricks(); // then, render the bricks again so the brick no longer appears on the screen
   }
}
```

This is one possible approach to solving your problem. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, Leaf the Legend. This helps a lot.